ELSA Workflow Routing Conflicts with nopCommerce Routing
I'm facing a problem with routing conflicts while registering Elsa server and Elsa HTTP endpoint with NopCommerce.
I have registered everything, and all is good except for the HTTP endpoints. By default, Elsa workflows use the endpoint /workflow. However, during debugging, it seems any URL for a custom workflow like /workflow/hellohttp is being picked up by this routing rule:
Executing endpoint 'Nop.Web.Controllers.CommonController.GenericUrl (Nop.Web)'
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[102]
    Route matched with {action = "GenericUrl", controller = "Common", area = ""}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult GenericUrl() on controller Nop.Web.Controllers.CommonController (Nop.Web).

My question is, how can I fix the routing conflict and make any request for /workflow/xx picked up by Elsa and not by NopCommerce?

Which version of Elsa workflows are you using?

@VahidNaderi 3.1

@VahidNaderi 3.1
